# define an class to a decorator, how to understand this code, which is wraps(func)(self) without assignment

Tags: python, decorator

I am reading a book whose name is python cookbook. In chapter 9.9, I don't understand the below code, especially in `__init__()`. It uses `wraps(func)(self)`  in `__init__()`, but it doesn't assign `wraps(func)(self)`  to `self`. Why `self.__wrapped__` can get the original function in `__call__()`?

```
import types
from functools import wraps


class Profiled:
    def __init__(self, func):
        wraps(func)(self)
        self.ncalls = 0

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ncalls += 1
        return self.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return types.MethodType(self, instance)


@Profiled
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


print(add(1, 2))
print(add(1, 3))
print(add.ncalls)
print(add)
```

I changed it to `self = wraps(func)(self)`, found that it also can work? Who can explain that? I also couldn't understand `self` in `self = wraps(func)(self)`. What's "self"?

Answer (score 2):

`wraps` is usually used as a decorator:

```
@wraps(some_other_func)
def func(...):
    ...
```

So that the decorated function has some of its metadata altered to make it look like it was defined with

```
def some_other_func(...)
```

Decorator syntax is just equivalent to

```
def func(...):
    ...

func = wraps(some_other_func)(func)
```

but when the value assigned to `func` is the *same* object that `func` originally referred to, the assignment isn't strictly necessary. That's not true for decorators in general, so the assignment is always made. But since you are calling the function returned by `wraps(func)` explicitly, you can omit the unnecessary assignment back to `self`.

Comment: If it *did* return a different (decorated) object here, an assignment to `self` wouldn’t help; you’d have to use `__new__`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I got it. I think that after ```wraps(func)(inner_func)```, ```inner_function``` will create a ```__wrapped__```  attribute.